# In what mode is Hive installed?

Tags: hive

Does hive installation have any specific mode?

Like for example, Hadoop installation has 3 modes: standalone, pseudo-distributed and fully distributed.
Similarly does Hive has any specific type of distribution?
Can Hive be installed in distributed mode?

Answer (score 3):

Hive actually provides you the option to run queries in 2 modes :

```
1- Map-Reduce mode
2- Local mode
```

Normally Hive compiler generates map-reduce jobs for most queries under the hood. These jobs are then submitted to the Map-Reduce cluster indicated by the variable:

```
mapred.job.tracker
```

While this usually points to a map-reduce cluster with multiple nodes, Hadoop also provided you the ability to run map-reduce jobs locally on the your standalone workstation. In order to run Hive queries in local mode you need to do this :

```
hive> SET mapred.job.tracker=local;
```

Details can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted.html#GettingStarted-Hive%252CMapReduceandLocalMode).

Comment: Can Hive be installed in distributed mode?

Comment: It is by default distributed.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by Hive being installed in distributed mode? in a cluster and single node..

Comment: If Hive is not running in local mode, the type of installation is governed by the underlying Hadoop setup i.e if your Hadoop is running is single node, Hive is also single node and if Hadoop is running in a fully distributed mode on a cluster then Hive will also be fully distributed. This is because of the fact that Hive all by itself doesn't have any processes like DNs or TTs. It just uses the TTs running already on your cluster to run the MapReduce task corresponding to your Hive queries. HTH